# How can I bulk rename files ending in invalid characters?

Tags: bash, linux-mint

I'm on linux Mint. I'd like to recursively rename files like

```
5f0c74603cbdca44fd877_source.mp4?Tag=1&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL2NkbjIub25seWZhbnMuY29tXC9maWxlc1wvOVwvOWNcLzljNTQzZGI1OGI0ZmQyYWI0YmExMzEzMTUxYmExZjdiXC81ZjBjNzQ2MDNjYmRjYTQ0ZmQ4Nzdfc291cmNlLm1wND9UYWc9MS


1904x2600_8c25949033674d6559bcfd3f02aed68d.jpg?Tag=1&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL2NkbjIub25seWZhbnMuY29tXC9maWxlc1wvYVwvYTFcL2ExNjZmMzRlZGZjMWU3NDRkOGIxZTEwYmZkNDIxNzJjXC8xOTA0eDI2MDBfOGMyNTk0OTAzMzY3NGQ2NTU5
```

to

```
5f0c74603cbdca44fd877_source.mp4
1904x2600_8c25949033674d6559bcfd3f02aed68d.jpg
```

so that I can copy files to an external hard drive.

Anyone know a quick one liner in bash that could accomplish this?

There's also another type of file that cannot be moved

```
index.html?C=D;O=D
```

How can I rename that to something that has valid characters?

Thanks!

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: consider using splat to match just enough to return one result, ```mv 5f* 5f.html```

Comment: @JamesBrown I'm using bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you search to remove all characters after first `?` (included).

```bash
for f in *\?*; do mv "$f" "${f%%\?*}"; done
```